# scrolling Tableview in callout in MKMapview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, mkmapview

I am having trouble with a UITableView inside a callout in MKMapView. The callout is a subview of an annotationView. And As I drag on UItableview, the Map captures the event and the map is moved and not the table view. Here is my code:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{
   CalloutView *detailsView = [[CalloutView alloc] initWithNibName:@"CalloutView" bundle:nil];
   detailsView.arrTitle=arrColTitle;
   detailsView.maxTitleWidthAllowed=60.0;
   [detailsView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
   [view addSubview:detailsView.view];
}
```

CalloutView nib file contains a tableview I am talking about.

Is it even possible to detect user events on uitableview in this case?

EDIT: I changed my code and it looks like I could pass on touchesbegan, touchesended, touchesmoved events to tableview meaning I called these events on uitableview. But still it does not scroll.

Thanks!!